# Excel automation isn't working in C++Builder XE7

Tags: excel, delphi, ole, delphi-xe7, c++builder-xe7

I am trying to use the code below to open an .xlsx file from C++Builder in RAD Studio XE7:

```
#include "ComObj.hpp"

Variant Excel = CreateOleObject("Excel.Application");
Variant Books = Excel.OlePropertyGet("Workbooks");
Excel.OlePropertySet("Visible", true);
// An escape character is missing but the problem remains
Books.OleProcedure("Open", L"D:\1.xlsx"); // exception here
```

But the last line causes exception with message:

Project2.exe raised exception class EOleException with message 'Unfortunately, we were unable to find the file TRUE.xlsx. It may have been moved, renamed or deleted?'.

[Screen with place where the source breaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRJ7Q.png)

The code in Delphi seems to work fine:

```
uses ComObj;

var
  Excel, Books: Variant;
begin
    Excel := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
    Books := Excel.Workbooks;
    Excel.Visible := True;
    Books.Open('D:\1.xlsx'); // code passes
end;
```

Does anyone know the solution?

**Update1:**
The following code in VB also works fine:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
 Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
 Dim xlBooks As Excel.Workbooks

 Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 Set xlBooks = xlApp.Workbooks

 xlApp.Visible = True
 xlBooks.Open ("D:\1.xlsx")
End Sub
```

**Update2:**
Sending a raw string literal causes the same [exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0Fb0.png).

`Books.OleProcedure("Open", uR"(D:\1.xlsx)");`

It also doesn't seem to be an environment problem. I tested the example at several computers with no effect.

Comment: Please don't change the question. Feel free to add more info in an edit. But don't remove the original question.

Comment: Sorry, added them, but also no changes. Seems like something with static_cast conversion on the screen, doesn't it?

Comment: The cast is working fine I think.

Comment: What happens when you change the filename to something other that `1`?

Comment: Error remains the same when I change the path to "D:\\file.xlsx"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ the backslash character is the escape character in string literals and so needs itself to be escaped. Instead of

```
L"D:\1.xlsx"
```

you need to write

```
L"D:\\1.xlsx"
```

The error message is strange though. It is almost as though some conversion in the COM dispatch code interprets the `1` as a truth value and converts it to text. You could try passing the filename as a `System::WideString` which might side-step the issue.

```
System::WideString filename = L"D:\\1.xlsx";
Books.OleProcedure("Open", filename);
```

What you are reporting seems almost too weird to be true though! I have to confess I'm having some trouble believing it because it is so outlandish.

Comment: Oops, sorry, added them, but also no changes.

Comment: My first thought was the same as David's, but you say the problem remains.  Next question:  Do you get the same problem if you try to open the file in an Excel macro using the VBA code which is equivalent to your Delphi Books.Open()?

Comment: System::WideString helped, thanks! Does it seems to be a bug? And is there any other way to transmit an wchar_t array?

Comment: Does look like a bug doesn't it. Something in the dispatch code is failing to convert C string to COM BSTR properly. Personally in your place I'd be looking to early bound COM.

Comment: I tried to use TExcelApplication class. There is a method Excel->Workbooks->Open(wchar_t*). The same situation comes up: if I use c_str() from String variable I get an error. But if I use c_bstr() from WideString variable, the method works.

Comment: It's a COM method so it expects a BSTR

Answer (score 1):

Just faced a similar problem with C++ Builder XE7 and thought I would share what I found.  Any attempt to set or send a string literal of any type caused either a Bad Variable Type error, was set as TRUE in Excel like Dmitrii or caused a memory error.

What I eventually found was that there is an OLEVariant type in C++ Builder that contains data types compatible with OLE automation and at runtime can convert as required.

I first tried changing all my Variant variables to OLEVariant without success but then was able to use a cast on any string I sent to make it work, even older char strings.  So you might try

```
Books.OleProcedure("Open", (OleVariant)L"D:\1.xlsx");
```

even without the WideString formatting it worked for what I was doing so this might work as well

```
Books.OleProcedure("Open", (OleVariant)"D:\1.xlsx");
```

As for escaping I'm not sure if you need to escape the backslash in the second case with a simple string or not.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this twice.  Thanks for saving me lots of grief.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems very specifically related to the use of C++ and thus the way that C++ compilers deal with literal strings (or at least this particular C++ compiler).  Quite what the problem is in this case I cannot say - it could even be a bug in the compiler since (seemingly) correct escaping doesn't address the problem.

You could employ various strategies to eliminate the possibility that it is handling of the literal string in this case.  But since this does involve a literal string and since you are using XE7 I believe you should be able to bypass this more explicitly by expressing the literal as a raw string (as per C++11, which is/should be supported by C++ Builder XE7):

```
Books.OleProcedure("Open", uR"(D:\1.xlsx)"); // uR indicates UTF-16 Raw string
```

Note that with raw string literals you specifically **do not** escape `\` chars.

Comment: @Deltics It is a stretch to imagine that there exists a compiler that cannot escape backslashes in literals.

Comment: Possibly, but if the problem was in the OLE objects, the file system or the OLE automation server then you would see the same result no matter what language was involved.  It's too much of a coincidence that the problem only arises when one particular language is being used.  And this is an Embarcadero compiler we're talking about.... a vendor not known for the quality of their work.  Certainly not lately.  Try the same C/C++ code in Visual Studio and see what happens ?

First eliminate the impossible...

Comment: @Deltics Escapes in literals work in all compilers. It's the COM dispatch that is unique to Emba. I can't imagine how they stuffed it up.

Comment: Ah yes, didn't spot the OleProcedure() intermediate.  As I said...  Not a vendor known for the quality of their work...  ;)